# How to use multiple CheckBoxList for product filtering?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code is filtering products page with one checkboxlist Items.I want use this code and filter product page with multiple checkboxlist Items.

Sample:

Product name: shoes, shirt, bag, etc.

Brand name: nike, adidas, etc.

For: Male, Femail, Child, etc.

Thanks for your help.

Code:

```
private void Bind()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "SELECT Id, ModelName FROM Model";

        string emStr = string.Empty;
        foreach (ListItem item in chkModel.Items)
        {
            emStr += item.Selected ? string.Format("'{0}',", item.Value) : string.Empty;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(emStr))
        {
            emStr = string.Format(" WHERE Id IN ({0})", emStr.Substring(0, emStr.Length - 1));
        }

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query + emStr))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: We do not know what you have in `Model` so it is hard to help. You need to pass the values from the other lists the same way as `chkModel.Items`

Comment: Model table fields: ModelName, ProductName, BrandName, ModelCode, Price. Insert one **Checkboxlist** for apiece field: **chkProductName**, **chkModelName**,**chkBrandName**,**chkPrice**. So i want filtering **GridView1** result by all **CheckBoxList Items**.